# Login backend in TYPO3 with Proxy

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, apache2, typo3, reverse-proxy

I use TYPO3 6.2 on Ubuntu behind a Proxy.

When I want to login in the backend, all the times I have this error :

> Your login attempt did not succeed
>
> Make sure to spell your username and password correctly, including upper/lowercase characters.

But I'm sur, the username and the password are good cause I try to create an other usr in the install fill and I have the same error with the new user.

I tried to change this conf but that doesn't work too.

```
[HTTP][adapter] = curl 
[HTTP][proxy_host] = http://proxy
[HTTP][proxy_port] = port
[SYS][curlUse] = 1
[SYS][curlProxyServer] = http://proxy:port
```

Edit : I don't use SSL

Edit2 : I need perhaps add something in my conf with Apache (It's compulsory to use proxy)

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80
<VirtualHost exemple.com:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        ServerName exemple.com
        ServerAlias www.exemple.com
        <Directory /var/www>
                Order Allow,Deny
                Deny from all
        </Directory>
        ProxyPass /exemple/ http://exemple1.local/

        ProxyPassReverse /exemple/ http://exemple1.local/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
        DocumentRoot /exemple/
        ServerName exemple1.local/
        <Directory /exemple/>
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Du you use SSL for the TYPO3 backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now, I can say that not possible like I what to do (I think.) So now I use two ServerNames...

Answer (score 0):

This error message can mean anything. You will see this error message for any error that occurs during login process to not disclose information.

A few things to try:

- can you login without the proxy?
- can you server store sessions at all?
- does your Proxy modify GET or POST parameters?
- ...

You can try to install a devlog extension and have a look at the extended login action protocol. You will need to enable `DLOG` in the install tool.

Comment: Yes, I can login.
Yes, I can store sessions.
No, my Proxy modify nothing.

I go try the devlog

Comment: Can you login into the install tool?

Comment: Yes, I can connect to the install tool.

Comment: Also via proxy? Because if you can do this, your server somehow cannot write into its session save path. The install tool saves sessions below typo3temp/*

Comment: I give you the bunty for the help. Thank you but we add a second server name.

Comment: Thanks. If this works for you, it might be easier :)